# PHP. Guzzle. Логирование запросов

Tags: php, сервер, логирование, backend, guzzle

Появилась следующая задача:
Есть запросы к API с помощью Guzzle. Есть логирование в ClickHouse (да это не важно даже). Как можно без какого-то вмешательства в Guzzle (в виде внедрения зависимостей тех же) просто взять и заставить все Requests логировать запросы по моим правилам? Максимально крутой экспириенс будет если получится не создавать новые классы, не вешать декораторы по всему коду или ещё какие-то подобные действия, которые надо будет поддерживать и ещё не упустить, пробежаться.

Может есть какой-то конфигуратор у Guzzle, который позволит это сделать? Заставить логирование вызывать мои функции и методы. Я не смог это нагуглить и в документации чего-то такого про логирование не увидел.

Буду благодарен любой помощи :)

Comment: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/handlers-and-middleware.html

Comment: Это хорошая идея, но все-равно требует манипуляций. Идея такова:

Есть несколько реквестор и есть даже логирование, допустим new Clinet())->get и потом LogClickHouse

Хочется, чтобы осталось new Client())->get, я удалил LogClickHouse и логирование продолжилось. 

Продолжаю копать вглубь газла, ищу решение. Хочется добиться минимальных требований.

Comment: вы разные экземпляры создаете всегда, или что?

Comment: унаследуйте свой класс от клиента этого, в конструкторе добавьте свое логгирование или в лбом другом месте и все дела

Comment: Да, похоже это может сработать. Нашёл два варианта. Буду пробывать :) Второй вариант - повесить StackHandler через конфиги и создать Middleware.